# Attendance Registration System

Tags: web-services, cloud-service

I am part of a community that hosts several events per year. We are looking for a service where people can register online for an event. No billing should be included as everything we offer is free.

A few hundred people are invited, but we only have a couple dozen places. It would be great if those people could see how many people have registered for the event and maybe also cancel their attendance. 
Shortly before the beginning, the registration should be closed and I need a list of the people who signed up for an event.

Comment: Would something like [EventBrite](https://www.eventbrite.sg/) work if you set tickets to $0?

Comment: Thanks, it does look pretty nice. There is just one thing that bothers me, the way that the invitations work. I would like to invite a group of people without sending them emails every single time. They should sign in to their account and see what events are available and then sign up for the event from there.